# Can not enter and change PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf file

Tags: postgresql, terminal, vi

I am running OSX, I am trying to change the PostgreSQL authentication options in the pg_hba.conf file. The problem is I can't get into it. I have tried

```
sudo su - postgres
```

Then used vi to try to edit it. When I open the file with vi, vi displays as if it's a new file, showing only tilde lines. If I try to write that new file, I get an error saying I am not able to do so.

PLease help, thanks

this is my directory:

```
$ sudo find / -name pg_hba.conf
Password:
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data/pg_hba.conf
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At a guess, you've tried to edit the file in a directory that doesn't actually exist, because the path on your system is different. It'd help if you showed the exact command you ran, the exact error message text, your version of PostgreSQL and how you installed Pg (Homebrew, EnterpriseDB packages, etc).

To edit `pg_hba.conf`:

In psql, run:

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

and see what location it reports. That's the file you must edit. If you can't get into `psql` you must locate it in the file system; try:

```
sudo find / -name pg_hba.conf
```

When you've found the correct path, you don't need to use `su` to edit it from a `postgres` login; just use:

```
sudo vim /path/to/pg_hba.conf
```

eg on my system:

```
sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

If you prefer to use a different editor, anything that can run from the command line should work, including most GUI editors.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I managed to get into it with vim and change it. It was exactly where I thought it was before though...I really am miffed about why I couldn't get into it before. You saved me though. thanks!

Comment: @A_funs Glad it worked out. Have fun with Pg. BTW, you can save some back-and-forth in future by posting exact command lines, exact copied-and-pasted error messages, etc; that makes it easier to write a good answer first time around.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way

```
 sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf
```